# conda not installing packages

Tags: anaconda, conda, python-module

I am unable to install packages through conda. When I run conda install, I get this output.

```
(base) C:\Users\Madhan_Kumar>conda install pytesseract
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

this is happening since I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda. conda was working properly before that.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new env specifically for this project that includes this dependency from the beginning? E.g., `conda create -n my_env python pytesseract` ?

Comment: @merv yeah i tried, but not working. Anyway, this is not for a project or anytihng, that was just a test library. Whatever library i try to install, i either get package not found error(even for the libraries which i was able to install before) or it gets stuck at solving environment.

Comment: Don’t use the base environment for this! What is the result when you try in a new environment?

Comment: @AMC, I tried by creating a new envronment, but i am getting the same output.

Comment: Can you share the command you used to create the environment? Your base environment might be broken in such a way that the rest of the install is affected, in which case remove and reinstalling Conda is your best bet.

Comment: @AMC , I reinstalled a few days ago, it is working fine now. Thanks for the help.